# Get value from DataSet column starting with DataGridView's row and column indexes

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sql-server-2012, dataset

I have the row and column indexes of a value in a DataGridView and I need to find the corresponding column value in the DGV's DataSet, matching on the ID field of the table.

So my DGV cell value is being accessed with:

```
dgvEmployees.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value().ToString()
```

The ID column for the DataSet is EmployeeID, which is found in the DGV with

```
dgvemployees.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value().ToString()
```

I know I can get a specific DataSet's row with

```
DirectCast(row, EmployeesDataSet.employeesRow).EmployeesID
```

and I've been iterating through the DataSet's row's Original and Current values with

```
EmployeesDataSet.employees(r)(c, DataRowVersion.Original).ToString()
```

and

```
EmployeesDataSet.employees(r)(c, DataRowVersion.Current).ToString()
```

respectively.

So, given all of that information, how can I compare the matching column in the DataSet to the known column in the DataGridView? I know the answer probably lies somewhere in the code I've offered here, I'm just not sure how to put it together to get what I need!

Comment: This is not entirely clear. First, why do you need to compare data in grid and the grid source, if the grid displaying exactly what is in the source? Second, here, `EmployeesDataSet.employeesRow` I am not sure. Is this your custom object? Because usually, the structure is `dataset.tables[x].rows[y]`. What object type is your `EmployeesDataSet`?

Comment: Are you not clear on the why or on what I'm trying to do? I need to compare the value from the DGV's cell to the corresponding DataSet's value, using the EmployeeID because the DGV's cell value may be different. Not sure how else to state what I'm trying to do.